# SwiftUI ScrollReader positions incorrectly when use padding

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, padding

I am using ScrollReader to scroll to objects in SrcollView. I use horizontal padding for content to have insets at corners, when I scroll to the fist or the last word.
Here is the demo

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
  @State var text: String = ""

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("", text: $text)
        .frame(minWidth: 100)
        .background {
          Color.blue
        }
      ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        Button("Scroll") {
          if let id = Int(text) {
            withAnimation {
              proxy.scrollTo(id, anchor: .center)
            }
          }
        }
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
          HStack {
            ForEach(0..<30) { i in
              Text("word\(i)")
                .id(i)
            }
          }.padding(.horizontal)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By tapping the button it scrolls to chosen word by it doesn't center it correctly, it is moved left.
(somewhy I can't attach picture)
The same is gonna be if use `anchor: .leading` - the word will be half hidden on the left.
Everything works great if remove padding. But it seems quite a bug to me.
Here is workaround, we can use `Spacer().frame(width: 8)` instead of padding on each side.

So what's the problem with `.padding(.horizontal)`

Comment: I have filed feedback for scroll position not working consistently (depends on padding / fonts long list etc), please file another feedback, my feedback is still open. More feedbacks filed chances are it might get noticed by Apple.